# Problem in Daylight Saving Time Switch

Tags: c, dst

A program I wrote about four years ago, which gets the date and time as follows:

```
get_the_date_and_time(char *string) 
{
    struct tm *now;
    time_t lt;
    lt = time(NULL);
    now = localtime(&lt);
    sprintf(string,asctime(now));
}
```

It is returning the time an hour late since the switch to Daylight Saving Time.

By changing my system date to April 5, I get the right time.

We've done a work-around for the project involved; this is just a heads up.

I suspect Microsoft's Daylight Saving Time mods for the expansion of the Daylight Savings Time stretch is, if not broken, somewhat damaged.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like your system isn't aware of the change to daylight savings in the US due to the 2005 Energy Policy Act (which [made DST a month longer from 2007 onwards](http://www.energy.ca.gov/daylightsaving.html)).

What version of Windows are you using, and have you kept it up to date with Windows Update?

EDIT: Also, is this linking statically or dynamically, and have you rebuilt since applying all patches etc? While I would *hope* it gets the information from the OS, it's possible that if you're linking statically some of it could be baked into your executable. (Ick.)

Comment: When he said "I suspect Microsoft's daylight savings mods", I took that as meaning that he'd already applied the patches.

Comment: That's possible - it would really help if the question could be clarified. Even just knowing the OS would be a good start...